# How to create admin with mysql script in magento 1.9.2.1?

Tags: magento

I lost my magento admin details while updating my sample data.how can i create another admin to my existing magento project.
Thank you

Comment: this might help you - http://www.atwix.com/magento/reset-admin-password-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Magento use **MD5** as encryption for passwords. if you want to change the password of admin simply go to your database and open `admin_user` table and edit the record which have `username` = `admin`.  and save it.

[image]